# How can I log out the user even if they don't respond to JavaScript's "confirm()"?

Tags: javascript, php

This was the initial code I was using:

```
setInterval(function(){
  r=confirm("You are about to be logged out! Press cancel if you want to remain logged in.");
  if (r == true){
    window.location.href = '../logout.php';
  }else{
    location.reload();
  }
},30000);
```

The confirm dialog awaits action from the user. If the action is "cancel", they remain logged in. If the action is "OK" the are redirected to the logout.php page. The issue is that if the user does not respond, they are not logged out after those elapsed 30 seconds.

Then I thought I may use two time intervals:

```
setInterval(function(){
  window.location.href = '../logout.php';
},60000);


setInterval(function(){
  r=confirm("You are about to be logged out! Press cancel if you want to remain logged in.");
  if (r == true){
    window.location.href = '../logout.php';
  }else{
    location.reload();
  }
},30000);
```

but since the confirm() method halts the script, the 60000 ms is never realised. Is there a way I can get this to work?

Comment: You are asking your users every 30 seconds if they want to stay logged in?

Comment: 1 minute is just an example. It's not the actual issue here. I could have written 600000.

Comment: What I tried to say is that you probably should overthink the concept. Imagine you are writing a question on Stackoverflow, a confirmation dialog opens in exact the moment you are going to press enter. You are logged out and your question is gone.

Comment: You're right, confirm halts the script. If you want to have script continuing to execute in the background, you might be better with a HTML-based modal

Comment: Say if they just leave their desktop, or close the browser without responding.

Comment: Then their session should expire on the server automatically eventually. I assume you have server-side session timeout, set to a sensible value? And if they closed the browser completely (not just the tab) then unless you have a "remember me" type of cookie set, it won't automatically log them back in next time they open it, because opening a new browser window starts a new session.

Comment: If they _"close the browser without responding"_ your script doesn't run.

Comment: if they "just leave their desktop", then the timer should continue to run (if you implement my HTML-modal suggestion) and eventually run the logout script. Sometimes JS does pause though, if the user moves to another tab in the browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my suggestion

1. start a timer that logs the user out
2. start a graceTimer to show a link
3. if link clicked, the timers restarts
4. if not, the user is logged out

https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/t5ejs72q/

```js
let tId, tId1;
const end = 15000, // change to whatever - 30 minutes
  grace = 3000, // 3 secs - should be 30 secs in real life
  timer = () => {
    clearTimeout(tId);
    tId = setTimeout(function() {
      // location.replace('../logout.php')
      console.log("logged out")
    }, end);
  },
  graceTime = () => tId1 = setTimeout(toggleGrace, end - grace),
  toggleGrace = () => document.getElementById("stayLink").classList.toggle("hide"),
  init = () => {
    timer();
    graceTime()
  };

document.getElementById("stayLink").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  toggleGrace();
  init()
})
init()
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" id="stayLink" class="hide">Stay logged in?</a>
```